# Erro ao executar "npm run dv"

Tags: laravel-5, npm

```
npm run dev
```

> @ dev /var/www/UpEvent
>   node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

module.js:549

> ```
> throw err;
> ^
> ```
>
> Error: Cannot find module
>   '/var/www/UpEvent/node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:609:3 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! @ dev: `node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js
>   NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress
>   --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script. npm ERR!
>   This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
>   logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/imacruz/.npm/_logs/2018-04-17T13_58_27_867Z-debug.log

Comment: Posta o conteúdo do seu webpack.conf. Além do mais, na mensagem diz que está tentando pegar um módulo não encontrado, logo, verifique se está instalado.

Comment: Já apaguei toda a pasta node_modules e reinstalei mas não vai, não estou encontrando esse arquivo webpack.conf não seria webpack.mix.js ?

Comment: Logo, entendeu qual arquivo eu estava falando, pois, sim é esse.

Comment: let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque o código lá. Se não souber como fazer, recomendo que faça o tour de como funciona o site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour